# How can I get input validation with Java using Scanner with regex.Pattern and arrays

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to apply some input validation to a simple Java application using java.util.regex.Pattern. Before adding the pattern matching I was able to get user input into my arrays as expected, but I can't figure out how to do this with the pattern matching included.

This lines seems to be problematic: in.nextLine(); Is it in the wrong place now that I have added the while statement with the pattern matching?

Here is the relevant chunk of code from my little app.

```
//These variables used during input validation
        String tempName;
        int tempGrade;

        //These regex patterns are for input validation
        //Names can be 1-15 letters and grades are 2 digits
        Pattern namePattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]{1,15}");
        Pattern gradePattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{2,2}");

        //Parallel arrays to hold last names and grades
        String[] names = new String[5];
        int[] grades = new int[5];


        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {


            for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter a name:");
                tempName = in.nextLine(); 
                System.out.println("Enter a grade:");
                tempGrade = in.nextInt();
                in.nextLine(); 
                while(!namePattern.matcher(tempName).matches()) {
                    System.out.println("Bad input. Try again");                 
                } 
                names[i] = tempName;
                grades[i] = tempGrade;
                }
```

Comment: You don't need Pattern, just use .matches() method.

Answer (score 3):

No. `in.nextLine()` is correct (and consumes the trailing newline from calling `nextInt()`). The problem is your loop.

```
while(!namePattern.matcher(tempName).matches()) {
    System.out.println("Bad input. Try again");     
    tempName = in.nextLine();  //<-- add this.            
}
```

Without updating `tempName`, if you enter the loop body you never leave because the condition is always true after printing your message.